# Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Date'

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to TypeScript. I'm trying to get today's date in `mm-dd-yyyy` format but I'm getting this error:

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Date'

Here's my code:

```
initCalendarYear() {
  var today = new Date();
  var dd = today.getDate();
  var mm = today.getMonth()+1; 
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
  if(dd < 10) {
     dd = '0'+dd;
  } 

  if(mm < 10) 
  {
     mm = '0'+mm;
  } 
  today = mm+'-'+dd+'-'+yyyy;
  console.log(today);
}
```

It should be straight forward. there's no rocket science. Please correct me where I am wrong.
I'm getting this error for following lines:

1. `dd='0'+dd;`
2. `mm='0'+mm;`
3. `today = mm+'-'+dd+'-'+yyyy;`

I'm taking help from:

[JavaScript : Display the current date](https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-basic-exercise-3.php)

Comment: Take into account that Typescript in conjunction with JavaScript, is strongly-typed. Thus when you declare a var to be Date you can not later assign a string to it. This code in JS would be fine

Comment: I think you should now start thinking in terms of static language where you cannot assign value of type A to variable which is declared to hold values of type B.

`Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Date'`. In my opinion you should spend time trying to understand the error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in strict types in TS.

Today is `Date` type and you try to reassign value with another type, in your case it is `String`.

In JS it would work, but in TS won't.

Answer (score 7):

`new Date()` is a date. You assign it to `var today` which implicitly sets the type of the variable to `Date`.

`mm+'-'+dd+'-'+yyyy` is a string. You try to assign it to `today` which is a `Date`. It isn't a Date, so you get an error. You can't change the type of a variable (unless you declare it to expressly allow multiple types in the first place)

Use a different variable name to store your string in.

(And the same goes for the other variables where you do similar things)